# Redirect to different URL onClick browser back - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

The scenario is I am on a page e.g. http://example.com/order-confirmation and the previous URL is /payment. Now when the user presses back button, I want to redirect them to home page i.e. to URL '/' but it's going back to /payment page.
I am using `react("^15.1.0")` and `react-router("^2.4.1")` and `react-router-redux("^4.0.4")` in my application.

I have tried following multiple answers on StackOverflow or git but all in vain.
E.g. I tried below:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

<Route
  path={`${AppPaths.ORDER_CONFIRMATION}/:orderId`} component={OrderConfirmationContainer} onLeave={(prevState) => routeBackHome(store, prevState)}
  onEnter={routeEntryHandler(store, nonGuestUserValidator)}
/>

const routeBackHome = (store, prevState) => {
    store.dispatch(push(`/`));
};
```

My routes:

```
export const createRoutes = store => (
<Route path={AppPaths.BASE} component={CheckoutAppContainer} onEnter={CheckoutAppContainer.fetchUserState(store)}>
<IndexRedirect to={`${AppPaths.BASE}/${AppPaths.BAG}`} />
<Route component={CheckoutWizardContainer} onLeave={() => clearNotifications(store)}>
  <Route
    path={AppPaths.BAG} component={CartContainer} onLeave={() => clearNotifications(store)}
    onEnter={() => updateStepNumber(store, 1)}
  />
  <Route
    path={AppPaths.PAYMENT} component={QuickCheckoutContainer} onLeave={() => clearNotifications(store)}
    onEnter={checkoutEntryHandler(store, 3)}
  />
</Route>
<Route
  path={`${AppPaths.ORDER_CONFIRMATION}/:orderId`} component={OrderConfirmationContainer}
  onEnter={routeEntryHandler(store, nonGuestUserValidator)}
/>
</Route>
);
```

Is there any way to override this behavior?
Please suggest...
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: please refer the edited question.

Comment: do you use the middleware to synchronize your browserHistory with your store as well in your redux store?

Comment: yes, I am using syncHistoryWithStore method of react-router-redux

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this); // if you need to bind callback to this
  }

  onUnload(event) { // the method that will be used for both add and remove event
    const gohome = confirm('go home?')
    if (gohome === true) {
      console.log('yay')
      window.location = 'http://yourhomepage.com'
    }else {
      console.log('yes')
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          Try with window location
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working. still going to last url i.e. /payment.

Comment: How does the other routes look like?

Comment: Can you paste them into the code? It may be related to your IndexRoute Component..Because I tried that in a CodePen and it works, so there must be something else we're missing here. To test it, you should log which components are loaded.  And if it's only the component loaded by /payment, then maybe I'm misunderstanding which "back button" are you talking about

Comment: @juancab : edited the question with my routes. It is going to home url for less than a sec and then back to previous url i.e. /payment. By "back button" I am talking about browser back-button.

Comment: when you open your homepage always redirect to /payment right?

Comment: @RahmatAligos : no

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

<Route
  path={`${AppPaths.ORDER_CONFIRMATION}/:orderId`} component={OrderConfirmationContainer} onLeave={(prevState) => routeBackHome(store, prevState)}
  onEnter={routeEntryHandler(store, nonGuestUserValidator)}
/>

const routeBackHome = (store, prevState) => {
    browserHistory.push('/');
};
```

Comment: import { browserHistory } from 'react-router' not working.
'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.